# JSQMessagesViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, chat, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am learning objective c programming through a udemy course taught by code coalition- I downloaded the last project from their github and have run into a snag while trying to get it work.

```
@interface CCChatViewController : JSQMessagesViewController <JSQMessagesViewDelegate,         JSQMessagesViewDataSource>
```

This is in my chat view controller, and I am getting an error 'Cannot find protocol for JSQMessagesViewDelegate or JSQMessagesViewDataSource'

Comment: Looks like a problem with importing the right header files. Can you check on these lines?

Comment: I'm not sure in which version the author changed the way it is implemented. Those delegates are not needed anymore. Check out the demo proyect.